# Get kml string from kmlObject in google earth plugin

Tags: javascript, kml, google-earth-plugin

I am working on an app with google earth plugin. I i have a KmlObject refrence, that i got from fetching a url. How can i extract the kml string representing the object? I think I once saw that it is possible, but I am searching it for a long time, and can't find it again.
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The [getKml](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_kml_feature#ab818d9e9b7255aef4f41bc2f6496de07) method is available on all objects that inherit from the abstract [KmlFeature](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_kml_feature).

Calling this will give you a string representation of the KML that describes the feature. ie.

```
var p = ge.createPlacemark(''); //create a placemark
p.setName('foo'); // set the feature name
console.log(p.getKml()); //get the feature kml
```